# Python pandas: ParserError: Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used

Tags: python, pandas, csv, delimiter

I try to open a csv file. I already know that there are two seperators used: , and ;.

```
df = pd.read_csv("TT.csv", sep=', |;', engine='python')
```

But then I constantly get this...

> ParserError: Expected 13 fields in line 61, saw 14. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

What should I do?

Comment: Please give an example of some lines from the file

Comment: You're using a multiple char delimiter in the sep parameter when you clearly stated that there are two separate delimiters used.

Answer (score 1):

one workaround to  `ParserError: Expected 13 fields in line 61, saw 14..` is let `read_csv` know about how many columns in advance.

Eg.

```
my_cols = [str(i) for i in range(45)] # create some row names
df_user_key_word_org = pd.read_csv(filepath+"user_key_word.txt",
                                   sep="\s+|;|:",
                                   names=my_cols, 
                                   header=None, 
                                   engine="python")
# I tested with s = StringIO(text_from_OP) on my computer
```